# Ubuntu mishap during update 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade

So during the upgrade from 18 to 20 my Gnome UI became unresponsive to mouse clicks. There was a point during the install where it sacked me if I wish to replace some system file, merge it or keep old. So while trying to do anything so that the install could just continue I succeeded by hitting enter on keyboard. This chose the 'n' option in the visible terminal (I believe this means it kept my version/old). I forgot to remember for which file that was maybe something in /etc/. Can some one help me so that I can see what are the changes and try merging by downloading the "new" version from somewhere. Are there upgrade logs saved somewhere where I can see what happened during upgrade?

Edit:
Ok so I found out what happened:

```
Configuration file '/etc/gdm3/custom.conf'^M
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.^M
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.^M
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:^M
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version^M
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version^M
      D     : show the differences between the versions^M
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation^M
 The default action is to keep your current version.^M
*** custom.conf (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? n^M
```

Where can I get the version of the file that ubuntu wanted to put so that I can make a diff merge?

Comment: Try looking at /var/log/apt/term.log

Comment: Thank you. Can you put the comments in an answer so that I can mark it. I was going to install a live USB an check but you saved me some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular configuration file, `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`, has all options commented out (#). If your file has an option(s) enabled, that's the change you made.

- Future readers: Different config files have different options disabled or enabled by default. This answer applies ONLY to `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`